# How to scrape additional pages of a webpage

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

With some help from the community, I was able to scrape some information off a webpage. However, I am facing some trouble scraping information off the additional pages of the website.

The code shown below is able to obtain the following information: ('date', 'type', 'registration', 'operator', 'fat.', 'location', 'cat') from each year of the webpage (from 1919 - 2019). An example of the URL by year is

https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year=1946

However, i realised that there are additional pages in each of the URLs by years such as

https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year=1946&lang=&page=2 https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year=1946&lang=&page=3 https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year=1946&lang=&page=4

Was wondering how to scrape the additional pages for each year?

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36'}


#start of code
mainurl = "https://aviation-safety.net/database/"
def getAndParseURL(mainurl):
   result = requests.get(mainurl)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'html.parser')
   datatable = soup.find_all('a', href = True)
   return datatable

datatable = getAndParseURL(mainurl)

#go through the content and grab the URLs
links = []
for link in datatable:
    if 'Year' in link['href']:
        url = link['href']

        links.append(mainurl + url)


#check if links are in dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(links, columns=['url'])

df.head(10)



#create empty datframe and empty list to store urls that didn't pull a table
results_df = pd.DataFrame()
no_table = []
#Loop through the URLs retrieved previously and append to results_df
for x in df['url']:
    try:
        html = requests.get(x, headers=headers).text   # <----- added headers
        table = pd.read_html(html)[0]    # <---- used pandas to read in the html and parse table tags. this will return a list of dataframes and want the dataframe in position 0

        results_df = results_df.append(table, sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)
        print ('Processed: %s' %x)
    except:
        print ('No table found: %s' %x)
        no_table.append(x)


results_df = results_df[['date', 'type', 'registration', 'operator', 'fat.', 'location', 'cat']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use beautifulsoup to check for the `<div>` tag that contains the number of pages, then it looks like you can just iterate through those. Might be a better way to do it, but I just added another try/except in there to deal with if additional pages are found:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36'}


#start of code
mainurl = "https://aviation-safety.net/database/"
def getAndParseURL(mainurl):
   result = requests.get(mainurl)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'html.parser')
   datatable = soup.find_all('a', href = True)
   return datatable

datatable = getAndParseURL(mainurl)

#go through the content and grab the URLs
links = []
for link in datatable:
    if 'Year' in link['href']:
        url = link['href']

        links.append(mainurl + url)


#check if links are in dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(links, columns=['url'])

df.head(10)



#create empty datframe and empty list to store urls that didn't pull a table
results_df = pd.DataFrame()
no_table = []
#Loop through the URLs retrieved previously and append to results_df
for x in df['url']:
    #Check for additional pages
    try:
        html = requests.get(x, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
        pages = soup.find('div',{'class':'pagenumbers'}).text.strip().split(' ')[-1]
        for page in range(1,int(pages)+1):
            page_x = x + '&lang=&page=%s' %page
            try:
                html = requests.get(page_x, headers=headers).text   # <----- added headers
                table = pd.read_html(html)[0]    # <---- used pandas to read in the html and parse table tags. this will return a list of dataframes and want the dataframe in position 0

                results_df = results_df.append(table, sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)
                print ('Processed: %s' %page_x)
            except:
                print ('No table found: %s' %page_x)
                no_table.append(page_x)

    except:
        try:
            html = requests.get(x, headers=headers).text   # <----- added headers
            table = pd.read_html(html)[0]    # <---- used pandas to read in the html and parse table tags. this will return a list of dataframes and want the dataframe in position 0

            results_df = results_df.append(table, sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)
            print ('Processed: %s' %x)
        except:
            print ('No table found: %s' %x)
            no_table.append(x)



results_df = results_df[['date', 'type', 'registration', 'operator', 'fat.', 'location', 'cat']]
```

Comment: This worked really well, thanks once again @chitown88! Btw, would there be any resource (e.g., website tutorial, book) you'd recommend for such advanced webscraping techniques?

Comment: o'rielly publishing usually has good ones, and they come out with newer editions which is good too. [link](https://www.amazon.com/Web-Scraping-Python-Collecting-Modern/dp/1491985577/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_14_t_0?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=XRQHBBF45PGMDDFFH0YF). Otherwise, I just sort of learn by doing and practising on different sites when I can.